# Bathroom Exhaust Fan with Light - Wiring

Tags: wiring, exhaust-fan

I have a new bathroom exhaust fan and light unit replacing an older unit of the same. Two switches — one for light and one for fan.

The wiring instructions show.

[image]

I have 4 wires coming to the unit. 2 hot (red and black), 1 neutral (white) and a ground.

For the fan: the white and black white wires coming from the fan are pre-twisted together. I’m assuming I connect these with the black or red wire coming from the desired switch.

I connect the other black/red wire the brown wire and white to white, correct?

N. Light refers to night light but I can’t find anything in the instructions about it. Aero Pure ABF80L6W

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I would need another hot wire and switch in order to use the night light, correct? So the blue wire would remain unconnected.

Comment: I recommend you use one switch for the room-illuminating light, and the other switch for the fan and night-light together.

Comment: That’s a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This is fairly simple

Your fan brings out the neutrals for the light/nightlight and fan separately for cases where they wind up on two different circuits or on opposite sides of a GFCI.  Since you only have a single circuit, though, you can simply wirenut both the fan and light neutrals to your white incoming neutral inside the fan's built-in wiring compartment and land the bare wire from that cable on the fan ground terminal, then wire up the hots as you'd wish.

Personally, I'd forego the nightlight myself, which means you cap off the blue wire, then connect black to one incoming switched hot and brown to the other incoming switched hot.  (If you wanted to use the nightlight, you'd put the fan and main light on the same switched hot, then use the other wire in the cable to bring always-hot to the nightlight, taking one of the switches out of service in the process.)  Obviously, you'll need the appropriate clamp or fitting for where your wiring enters the fan's terminal compartment, as well.